# Decodable that inits from an array

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I have a JSON array of objects. Simplified, it has this form:

```
[
  {"name": "Tinky Winky"},
  {"name": "Dipsy"},
  {"name": "Laa-Laa"},
  {"name": "Po"}
]
```

I can create a struct `Tubby` can can decode an individual instance from the array:

```
struct Tubby: Codable {
  let name: String
}
```

I'd like to create a struct `Tubbies` that can decode from the array of JSON:

```
struct Tubbies: Codable {
   let tubbies: [Tubby]

   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
     // What goes here?
     tubbies = ???
   }
```

… but now I'm stuck with how I should decode? I'd like to just do:

```
   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
     // What goes here?
     tubbies = decoder.decode([Tubby].self)
   }
```

But `Decoder` doesn't offer a `decode`. It has:

```
    /// Returns the data stored in this decoder as represented in a container
    /// keyed by the given key type.
    ///
    /// - parameter type: The key type to use for the container.
    /// - returns: A keyed decoding container view into this decoder.
    /// - throws: `DecodingError.typeMismatch` if the encountered stored value is
    ///   not a keyed container.
    func container<Key>(keyedBy type: Key.Type) throws -> KeyedDecodingContainer<Key> where Key : CodingKey

    /// Returns the data stored in this decoder as represented in a container
    /// appropriate for holding values with no keys.
    ///
    /// - returns: An unkeyed container view into this decoder.
    /// - throws: `DecodingError.typeMismatch` if the encountered stored value is
    ///   not an unkeyed container.
    func unkeyedContainer() throws -> UnkeyedDecodingContainer

    /// Returns the data stored in this decoder as represented in a container
    /// appropriate for holding a single primitive value.
    ///
    /// - returns: A single value container view into this decoder.
    /// - throws: `DecodingError.typeMismatch` if the encountered stored value is
    ///   not a single value container.
    func singleValueContainer() throws -> SingleValueDecodingContainer
```

Both <del>`singleValueContainer`</del> (this was a mistake, as the answers clarify – thanks!) and `unkeyedContainer` throw for the array with a message suggesting that they don't support an array. Can I use `container(keyedBy:)`, and what should I pass as the key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it was a good approach, since `[Tubby].self` is simple enough to use anywhere.
But if you just want to wrap the array inside another type, you should have something like this:

## Detailed version:

```
struct Tubbies: Codable {
    let tubbies: [Tubby]
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        self.tubbies = try container.decode([Tubby].self)
    }
}
```

---

## Shorter version:

```
struct Tubbies: Codable {
    let tubbies: [Tubby]
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        tubbies = try [Tubby](from: decoder)
    }
}
```

---

## Usage:

```
let tubbies: Tubbies = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Tubbies.self, from: jsonData)
```

Comment: Another option would be `tubbies = try [Tubby](from: decoder)`

Comment: Great, thanks! I think I didn't properly look at `singleValueContainer()` – I thought I'd tried it and that it threw an error! Many thanks for this. The shorter version is nicely concise and emphasises that `Decodable` things are things that `init` from a `Decoder`, which I like.